# Problem with implementing ViewPager2. The right way

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

**I was building this window**

[image]

**Problem:**

I used composite transformers to make it look like this, and I give some paddingStart and paddingEnd. But it is working only when I swipe the item which is standing in the center. When I swipe on a blank space or side items it is not working(I mean, I can't swipe at all).

My viewPager2:

```
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/apod_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:paddingStart="60dp"
            android:paddingEnd="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container_fragment_gallery" />
```

Transformations:

```
    binding.apodViewPager.clipToPadding = false
    binding.apodViewPager.clipChildren = false
    binding.apodViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
    binding.apodViewPager.getChildAt(0).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
    val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(60))
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
        val r = 1 - abs(position)
        page.scaleY = 0.9f + r * 0.07f
    }
    binding.apodViewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)
```

**Question:**
Is it supposed to be like that or can I make it what I wanted?